# Default date with formatDate format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uidatepicker

I can't figure this out from the documentation, but I want to set the default date of a datepicker input in the same format as the datepicker's display *without* having to do my own parsing.  E.g.:

```
$("#dp").datepicker({
    altField: '#helper',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    formatDate: 'm/d/Y',
}).val($("#helper").val())
```

This will display the datepicker in put as `2013-03-07` (as you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/zaG5z/)  However when you select a date it does display it as "m/d/Y."  Even selecting the same date makes it `03/07/2013`.  Is there any way to trigger that format from the initial value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#dp").datepicker({
    altField: '#helper',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    dateFormat: 'm/d/yy',
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date($("#helper").val()));
```

The important thing here is to use the `setDate` method. Previously you were  simply setting the `val()`, which was setting the value of the `input` but was not having any effect on the `datepicker`.

Comment: That's great, but is there any way to prevent the datepicker from opening too (or just hide it immediately)?  I tried with `hide`, but that didn't do it

Comment: @ExplosionPills I think this could be a bug. In the fiddle, if I choose `jQuery UI 1.9.2` from under `Frameworks & Extensions` and remove the reference to `jquery-ui-git.js` from `External References`, then the datapicker does not open on calling `setdate`.